# switch iframe selenium Python without ID

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I'm trying to find an input element in Selenium with Python.
I can't find it because the `input` is inside of an `iframe`.
I have try to switch in that `iframe` but I don't have an ID of `iframe`.
below the code:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width" src="https://.........." frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

and this is the code of the `input`:

```
<input type="tel" id="cvNumber" tabindex="0" data-shortname="cvv" maxlength="4" placeholder="XXX" class="mod-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm" autocomplete="off" value="">
```

I don't know how to switch because there isn't the ID of the `iframe`.

I need to write inside of the `input` the CVV code with send keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `xpath` to find the iframe, so something like `"//iframe[@class='credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width']"` as your find_by_xpath condition.

```
my_iframe=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@class='credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width']")
driver.switch_to.frame(my_iframe)
```

A more robust version of the above would be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

my_iframe=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@class='credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(my_iframe))
```

Switch back to default content like so:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: You can't send keys to iframe. First you identify and switch to the desired `iframe`. Then you identify and send keys to the desired `input`.

Comment: Thanks so much it's work.....

How can i turn back out of the iframe?

Comment: Added `driver.switch_to.default_content()` to answer body.